# how to estimate confidence interval when p is close to 0 for binomial distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I was trying to get confidence interval for $\hat{p}$. However, the estimated p in the population is close to zero. So I am wondering how I can calculate the confidence interval when p is that small? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Thanks!